# Ways to create a huge inverted index

Tags: database, information-retrieval, inverted-index

I want to create a big inverted index of around 10<sup>6</sup> terms. What method would you suggest? I'm thinking in fast binary key store DBs like Tokyo cabinet, voldemort, etc. **Edit:** I've tried MySQL in the past for storing a table of two integers to represent the inverted index, but even with the first column having a db index, queries were very slow. I think for those situations a SQL database has too much overhead, overhead of transactions, query parsing, etc. I'm searching for what technologies or algorithmic approaches would scale while having good response times and performance. I'm rolling my own solution for research purposes.

Comment: Can you give some intended application details? Have you considered using an open-source FTS application, such as Lucene or Sphinx?

Comment: AFAIK, if you use something like Voldemort, you will not be able to search for texts containing word combinations, unless you index them in advance. As this is a very basic operation in IR, consider this design decision carefully.

Comment: Why not? I think I can do several queries for each term and then do set operations on the sw layer above.

Comment: You need to read "How to ask questions the smart way"

Comment: @Martin What part of the question you don't understand?

Comment: piotr,i think martin means you would get better answers if you mentioned things like why you are rolling your own vs using an existing method, what exactly it is you are trying to index and what kinds of searches you want to do, etc.  Also, are you looking for algorithm help, library recommendations, coding tips?  Martin is talking about a specific document btw:  http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 3):

The question is somewhat vague, so I think the only answer I can give is: use a "generalized inverted index" ([GIN index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/gin-intro.html)) in PostgreSQL to create whatever kind of inverted index you want. All the hard work is done for you: it uses the write-ahead log for crash safety, internally uses btree structures for performance, and it's part of a mature database management system.

If your problem is full text search, then postgresql's [full-text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/textsearch.html) is already built for you and can use GIN internally.

Answer (score 0):

That is very cool you're trying to roll your own.  Perhapstudy up on Lucene's inverted index file format?
http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_1_0/fileformats.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely consider [Lucene](http://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=lucene&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html&ei=3sfyTuD-DM3hrAeIpszcDw&usg=AFQjCNH0fmo4p2Rx6FykJYYCWeS_CqYozw) for indexing as its basically the pre-eminent indexer right now. In fact I'm currently considering it for indexing my database of images. The "default" language is Java but it has been ported to other languages such as [CLucene](http://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=clucene&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http://sourceforge.net/projects/clucene/&ei=-sfyTrKJAsHSrQeRk7icCQ&usg=AFQjCNEh_im-HDpB3rZO44euIA5fhswj4Q) for C++, [PyLucene](http://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=pylucene&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/&ei=E8jyTouwCY-GrAeAtInSDw&usg=AFQjCNGB0DcmJP_BUbSno_8HBxZvE46xkg) for python.

A quick tutorial can be found [here](http://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=lucene%20tutorial&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CC4QFjAB&url=http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html&ei=J8jyTsniM8bjrAf3vJkG&usg=AFQjCNFnyxYBUc3qSOVnn6RVAtpBLSDMxA).