# Decorators for selective caching / memoization

Tags: python, memoization, python-decorators, joblib, klepto

I am looking for a way of building a decorator `@memoize` that I can use in functions as follows:

```
@memoize
my_function(a, b, c):
    # Do stuff 
    # result may not always be the same for fixed (a,b,c)
return result
```

Then, if I do:

```
result1 = my_function(a=1,b=2,c=3)
# The function f runs (slow). We cache the result for later

result2 = my_function(a=1, b=2, c=3)
# The decorator reads the cache and returns the result (fast)
```

Now say that I want to **force a cache update**:

```
result3 = my_function(a=1, b=2, c=3, force_update=True)
# The function runs *again* for values a, b, and c. 

result4 = my_function(a=1, b=2, c=3)
# We read the cache
```

At the end of the above, we always have `result4 = result3`, but not necessarily `result4 = result`, which is why one needs an option to force the cache update for the same input parameters.

How can I approach this problem?

## Note on `joblib`

As far as I know [`joblib`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/) supports `.call`, which forces a re-run, but it [does not update the cache](https://twitter.com/GaelVaroquaux/status/562735568346689536).

## Follow-up on using `klepto`:

Is there any way to have `klepto` (see @Wally's answer) cache its results by default under a specific location? (e.g. `/some/path/`) and share this location  across multiple functions? E.g. I would like to say

```
cache_path = "/some/path/"
```

and then `@memoize` several functions in a given module under the same path.

Comment: `functools.lru_cache` is a memoization decorator that provides a way to clear the entire cache (but not a specific call like in your example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest looking at `joblib` and `klepto`.  Both have very configurable caching algorithms, and may do what you want.

Both definitely can do the caching for `result1` and `result2`, and `klepto` provides access to the cache, so one can `pop` a result from the local memory cache (without removing it from a stored archive, say in a database).

```
>>> import klepto
>>> from klepto import lru_cache as memoize
>>> from klepto.keymaps import hashmap
>>> hasher = hashmap(algorithm='md5')
>>> @memoize(keymap=hasher)
... def squared(x):
...   print("called")
...   return x**2
... 
>>> squared(1)
called
1
>>> squared(2)
called
4
>>> squared(3)
called
9
>>> squared(2)
4
>>> 
>>> cache = squared.__cache__()
>>> # delete the 'key' for x=2
>>> cache.pop(squared.key(2))
4
>>> squared(2)
called
4
```

Not exactly the keyword interface you were looking for, but it has the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Wally. I already use `joblib` and couldn't find a way of doing what I ask (the closest thing is `.call`, but as I mention in my note, it doesn't do what I need). I will look into `klepto`.

Comment: I see your edit. I believe `klepto` does what you are looking for as it provides a `dict` interface to any cache, and also provides a `pop` method for the cache -- it provides all `dict` methods, actually.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks Wally. It looks like a more complete library for memoization specifically than joblib. Great to know. On this note, do you happen to know how to do the above with **disk** persistance?

Comment: I believe that `klepto.archives.dir_archive` creates an archive on disk with one entry per file, while `klepto.archives.file_archive` creates an archive on disk with all entries in a single file.  Additionally, you can use one of the `SQL` archives to write to disk.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21447994/4482921. I also remember another better example on SO, but can't seem to find the link offhand.

Comment: I have added a note to the OP to fully clarify this. I have notified Mike McKearns in case he can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
import cPickle


def memoize(func):
    cache = {}

    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        force_update = kwargs.pop('force_update', None)
        key = cPickle.dumps((args, kwargs))
        if force_update or key not in cache:
            res = func(*args, **kwargs)
            cache[key] = res
        else:
            res = cache[key]
        return res
    return decorator
```

The decorator accepts extra parameter `force_update` (you don't need to declare it in your function). It pops it from `kwargs`. So it you did't call the function with these parameters OR you are passing `force_update = True` the function will be called:

```
@memoize
def f(a=0, b=0, c=0):
    import random
    return [a, b, c, random.randint(1, 10)]


>>> print f(a=1, b=2, c=3)
[1, 2, 3, 9]
>>> print f(a=1, b=2, c=3) # value will be taken from the cache
[1, 2, 3, 9]
>>> print f(a=1, b=2, c=3, force_update=True)
[1, 2, 3, 2]
>>> print f(a=1, b=2, c=3) # value will be taken from the cache as well
[1, 2, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it yourself:

```
def memoize(func):
    cache = {}
    def cacher(a, b, c, force_update=False):
        if force_update or (a, b, c) not in cache:
            cache[(a, b, c)] = func(a, b, c)
        return cache[(a, b, c)]
    return cacher
```

Answer (score 1):

This is purely with regard to the follow-up question for `klepto`…

The flowing will extend @Wally's example to specify a directory:

```
>>> import klepto
>>> from klepto import lru_cache as memoize
>>> from klepto.keymaps import hashmap
>>> from klepto.archives import dir_archive
>>> hasher = hashmap(algorithm='md5')
>>> dir_cache = dir_archive('/tmp/some/path/squared')
>>> dir_cache2 = dir_archive('/tmp/some/path/tripled')
>>> @memoize(keymap=hasher, cache=dir_cache)
... def squared(x):
...   print("called")
...   return x**2
>>> 
>>> @memoize(keymap=hasher, cache=dir_cache2)
... def tripled(x):
...   print('called')
...   return 3*x
>>>
```

You could alternately use a `file_archive`, where you specify the path as:

```
cache = file_archive('/tmp/some/path/file.py')
```

Comment: Great. Thanks @Mike! I will read the docs, but what are the assumptions behind the particular keymap you used? i.e. `keymap=hashmap(algorithm='md5')`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "assumptions"... but maybe this link will clarify: https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto/blob/master/klepto/keymaps.py, and the set of "encodings" can be found here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto/blob/master/klepto/crypto.py  I used the keymap that was being used in the given example.  Let me know if the above doesn't answer what you were asking.